# Animating a THREE.Points object

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to load a model from Blender, apply a PointsMaterial to it and animate it. So far, I've been able to load the model and animate it successfully as long as I use a material other than `THREE.PointsMaterial` to create the mesh.

When I create a `THREE.Points` object, the animation doesn't play. I noticed that when I set the PointsMaterial's `morphTargets` property to `true`, there's a warning saying that there is no such property of `PointsMaterial`. Does Threejs not support animation of Points objects using morph targets?

monster refers to a mesh that works when animated. It uses the loaded geometry and material. ParticleSystem is the the `THREE.Points` object.

Code:

```
function loadObject(path){
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load(
        path,

        function(geometry, materials){  
            var material = materials[ 0 ];
            material.morphTargets = true;
            material.color.setHex( 0xffaaaa );
            monster = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
            monster.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
            var s = .003;
            monster.scale.set( s, s, s );

            var particleMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff,
                size: .005,
                morphTargets: true
            });

            particleSystem = new THREE.Points(geometry, particleMaterial);
            particleSystem.morphTargetInfluences = monster.morphTargetInfluences;
            particleSystem.morphTargetDictionary = monster.morphTargetDictionary;
            particleSystem.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            particleSystem.scale.set(s, s, s);

            particleSystem.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
            particleSystem.updateMatrix();
            particleSystem.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            scene.add(particleSystem);
            mixer.clipAction( geometry.animations[ 0 ], particleSystem )
                    .setDuration( 5 )           // one second
                    .startAt( - Math.random() ) // random phase (already running)
                    .play();                    // let's go
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: `THREE.Points` do not support morphs. three.js r.86